# Error when doing "docker save" :open.docker_temp_186536267: read-only file system

Tags: image, docker

I want save a docker image as a tar file, but failed

I got images:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
golint              latest              075f4c382720        28 minutes ago      788MB
<none>              <none>              bb0aaa77781c        About an hour ago   781MB
<none>              <none>              2c8079482c47        2 hours ago         781MB
<none>              <none>              911e38aa48e8        2 hours ago         781MB
<none>              <none>              9c40a6f74947        2 hours ago         781MB
<none>              <none>              3c31ac0f697b        3 hours ago         781MB
<none>              <none>              7e04f58c859d        3 hours ago         256MB
<none>              <none>              5c2c67944e4c        4 hours ago         760MB
golang              1.10                6fd1f7edb6ab        2 months ago        760MB
golang              1.9-alpine          b0260be938c6        8 months ago        240MB
```

The first image which is I want save

```
sudo docker save -o golint.tar 075f4c382720
```

the message is ：

```
open .docker_temp_186536267: read-only file system
```

where can I find the file ".docker_temp_186536267"?

Can I change the rights of the file?

what should  I do

Comment: `where can I find the file` - you can find it exactly at the same place where `golint.tar` will be stored. Looks like Docker first saves content to the temporary file and then changes its name to the desired one (https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/cfb85db180f79c4100e58e96ce2ed99a3cc23417/components/cli/cli/command/utils.go#L20).

Comment: So, check the mount to which you try to write the `golint.tar`.